# Angular Datatable Exact Match is not working(Not jQuery DataTable)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var val = $scope.gender;    
$scope.dtInstance.DataTable.column(9).search(val).draw();
```

This is my code to filter **Gender** column. It shows either no result or full result (not exact match).

Comment: Can you just add some more code. Because we don't know what is the variable val. Moreover search() only take one parameter which is a string or a regex. Why send it 3 ?

Comment: Thanks For ur Reply @Gerald Chablowski....I ve 6 rows inwhich 4 male rows and 2 Female Rows.  If I Choose male It ll show the Full Rows instead of 4 rows.

Comment: From where you are getting the gender details?

Comment: From AutoComplete @rajkumar-r

Comment: When you make a console.log of $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.column(9)  or val do you have a strings ?